# Couldn't install iOS app in the device

Tags: xcode, device

I have an app with development certificates and provisioning profile and I need that to be installed in 
a customer device.
I don't have UDID of the device that customer is trying out.
I would like to solve this problem without disturbing customer of asking his UDID and all.

Comment: Use TestFlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add **UDID** in provisioning profile and sign the app with that so that you can run it on the device.

Speaking of development provisioning profile.

You have to install the development provisioning profile in the device then only you can run the app in the development device.

**Use for Development** was removed from Xcode in Xcode 6 and later. It is no longer possible to do this for devices using Xcode 6 or later, even with the Devices page

Try going to **Window->Devices**. You should see your attached device in the list so right click on the device and select **Show Provisioning Profiles**.It will show a window where you can **add your profile**.